# OpenCv Java Android: Get list of all matching led light with their brightness value.

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, android

[Link To Image. Please Look at Image to Understand Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBTa7.png)

I have a bigger problem to solve but I have to take a small step first.

**Bigger Problem Statement:** In above-Linked Image, There is a series of Led Lights and a Digit next to them. I have to Read the Digit (Not Those F and R Letters) of Led which is currently Glowing. And this should happen when You open your Android Phone camera and Hold in front of this device. I understand that it is a much bigger Problem and Need a lot of ML and OCR algorithms to solve my problem.

**Reduced Problem Statement:** But by Myself, I have figured it out a simple way of solving the above problem in a little tricky way (**If Possible, Please help**).  What I want to do is to process this Image using OpenCV Java Library and Somehow read those Switched On or Switched Of LED lights and somehow stored their brightness value values into an Array and It must be sequential From Top to Bottom along with some brightness data so that I can figure out later that this LED was on or off.  So using this simple logic I can solve this problem for now without going through all those ML DL and OCR algorithm because I have to deliver it within 3 Days.

So now the issue is that I am new to OpenCV. Till now I have figured it out that using below

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {}
```

I can Get a Frame from Live Android Camera. and then I can do some processing over this  frame/image. Also, I have tried many ad-hoc approaches Which I found over SOF, But nowhere I could figure out How can I solve my problem. 
Is there any way to detect all those Switched On/Off LEDs brightness data and can be stored in an array in sequence from Top to bottom?

Any help or approach will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I experimented to find all Led Light By First finding all the contours and then Compare the contours with the same area. But When I am doing this in Live camera and OnCameraFrame, Each Contours area keeps changing. I don't think just matching the area of contours is going to solve my problem.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?